# LaTeX Appendix in wrong order

Tags: appendix

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX, document class `article`. I experience the following issue in adding an appendix to my thesis.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} 

\begin{document}

        \input{9-Appendix.tex}

**9-Appendix.tex**

\begin{appendices}

\section{Tables and figures}\label{appendix:A}

\subsection{...}
\begin{table}[h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|l|@{}}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{First table caption}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{landscape}
\subsection{...} 
\begin{longtable}{lllllll} 
\caption{Second table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Third table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Fourth table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Fifth table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Sixth table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\section{Historical series on ...} \label{appendix:B}
\par Text

\end{appendices}
    
\end{document}
```

Now the issue is that my appendix B is appearing somewhere between the first/second subsection of Appendix A, instead of right after the last subsection.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Using `\begin{subappendices} \end{subappendices}` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Putting together the snippet you gave does not show the problem, so there is something else going on.

Comment: I tried to create a MWE, please excuse me if this is not what you expect!

Comment: I think that the `[h]` float placement is not working like you expect. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Comment: Also, `\usepackage{placeins}` would fix it too.

Comment: Thank you. Your first suggestion resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, this now runs:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Tables and figures}\label{appendix:A}

\subsection{...}
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% use resizebox with textwidth
\begin{tabular}{ l | l }
  {\bf Symptom} & {\bf Metric} \\
\hline
This is a & rather small table
\end{tabular}% close resizebox
}
\caption{First table caption}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{landscape}
\subsection{...} 
\begin{longtable}{lllllll} 
Some & really & really & long & text & goes & here\\
\caption{Second table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Some & text & goes & here
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Third table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Some & text & goes & here
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Fourth table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Some & text & goes & here
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Fifth table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Some & text & goes & here
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Sixth table caption}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\section{Historical series on ...} \label{appendix:B}
\par Text

\end{appendices}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: table with resizebox]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I provided a more complete code now.